# Switches between Dialog in Microsoft Bot Framework (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I was coded up a bot on Microsoft Bot Framework. I have used LUIS language model. 
Below is my piece of code:

```
bot.use(builder.Middleware.dialogVersion({ version: 1.0, resetCommand: /^reset/i }));
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('GoogleHome', [

    function (session, args) {
    if(builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'cookingtips'))
    {
            quickReply(session, args)
    }
    if(builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'wakingtips'))
    {
            //My rest of the code
    }

}])
```

Here is the code for my quickReply

```
function quickreply(session, args){

    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                .text("Let me know the date and time you are comfortable with..")
                .suggestedActions(
                    builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                        session,[
                            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "CookingTips", "CookingTips"),
                            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "WalkingTips", "WalkingTips")

                        ]
                    )
                );
            builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, ["CookingTips", "WalkingTips"]), function(session,results) {
             console.log(results);
            session.send('So I understand you want a cooking tip ' +  results + ' right now');
            session.endDialog();
        }}
```

I am able to get the quick reply and on clicking which nothing happens. I see the following in my console:

```
.BotBuilder:prompt-choice - Prompt.returning([object Object])
.BotBuilder:prompt-choice - Session.endDialogWithResult()
/ - Session.endDialogWithResult()
```

Instead, I want this the message to be sent to my LUIS or at least display the acknowledgment message as written in the callback function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As your `quickReply()` function doesn't create a new dialog, so the `endDialog()` will terminal current dialog and as you don't have a parent dialog, which cannot return to resume one.

You can leverate the `next` middle to pass the value, modify your code as:

```
intents.matches('GoogleHome', [

    function (session, args, next) {
    if(builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'cookingtips'))
    {
            quickReply(session, args, next)
    }
    if(builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'wakingtips'))
    {
            //My rest of the code
    }

},(session,result)=>{
//get the user choice here
    console.log(result);
    session.send(JSON.stringify(result));
}])
```

**quickReply**

```
function quickRelpy(session, args, next) {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .text("Let me know the date and time you are comfortable with..")
        .suggestedActions(
            builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                session, [
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "CookingTips", "CookingTips"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "WalkingTips", "WalkingTips")

                ]
            )
        );
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, ["CookingTips", "WalkingTips"]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary. I tried but it did not work properly. Can you fill the code for getting the user choice? I feel I am doing it properly.

Comment: add some code snippet, to make it more clear. basiclly, your bot will recieve the users' message in the next waterfall.